# change background of one element and all its children when it is hovered jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, hover, children

I have a table which all `<tr>` that contains a lot of `<div>` and each one can contains many others (they are generated automatically)

then, I want to change `backgounrd-color` of each `<tr>` and all of children (`<div>` and children of `<div>` (others div)) when the mousemove the `<tr>`

then I used this :

```
$('.ui-datagrid-column').live('mousemove',function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            $(this).children().css('background-color', 'red');
            //ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content

        });
         //.ui-layout-container
        $('.ui-datagrid-column').live('mouseleave',function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
            $(this).children().css('background-color', 'white');
        });
```

but it doesn't change the background of the div inside the `<tr>`

how can I achive that

Comment: I can't see any problems with your code. Maybe you could use `background-color: inherit;` on your divs using `.ui-datagrid-column *' selector?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this effect very easily with just CSS.

Basically, you would set `tr:hover *` in your CSS with the `background-color` you want and it will be inherited by all of the elements below it. So now when you hover over that row it will override or set the background color of your elements in the `tr`.

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewMFY/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.ui-datagrid-column').hover(function(){$(this).addClass('background');
    $(this).children.addClass('background'); 
    //this will add a background class (something like background-color: red;)
    //I guess this will work, I never added classes to children
    }
    ,function(){$(this).removeClass('background');
    $(this).children.removeClass('background')
    //this will remove it again on mouse out
});
```